# Java Robot get focus of other application

Tags: java, awtrobot

I have a java Robot program ,where it can type a word on notepad,word etc,.

But the problem is i am **not getting focus of window application**, when i tried to enter the cursor in its textbox manually by using **ALT-TAB**,

And the application is not available in the list ,while doing ALT-TAB , 
also it is not visible in **Task Manager-> Application tab** 
but, it is available with **Processes tab of Task Manager**.
Is there any solution  to get focus of that windows application for keyPress using Java Robot.

Also ,in some other PC's ,i am getting Clear Focus of the application when i put the cursor manually after running the java robot program. I have installed **JDK1.6** in all my PC's. It is not working only in my PC's.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm thinking that you may need to use JNA for this, but I'm not sure until you put in the effort to clarify your question, that is, if you still need our help.

Comment: my java program is intended to type on a window based form application, when i move the cursor to the text box of that application, it is not typing automatically, but at the same time when i put the cursor in notepad it started typing please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your best bet is to use JNA to allow you to make system calls.

Assuming a Windows program, you could use JNA to make calls to the user32.dll including dll functions such as `FindWindowEx(...)` and `SetForegroundWindow(...)` to set the window of your choice to the foreground.

Comment: Thank you sir, can u give me some links or code , i tried to run a jna program , unable to run please help me

Comment: Thank you sir, and i want to know, why the cursor gets the control of that window application and starts typing in other PC's and not in my pc. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the focus of the other app, you could put your robot to the background, returning whatever was in the foreground previously (ie your target app) to get the focus.

Comment: I am executing my java program using command prompt, how to make it as a background process please explain me with some coding